# Force Mime Type in Browser (with Javascript)

Tags: javascript, mime-types

[I imagine that this is impossible due to security concerns, but:]

Is it possible to force the browser to handle a file with a certain mime type **without controlling the server?** I'm serving up files from file:// (on the client's machine itself) and I'd like to get text files to open in whatever their associated text editor is.

Note: Firefox just opens the file for viewing, which is not the desired behavior. I've tried changing the file extension even to something unknown, which does not help.

Comment: Just another reason why Firefox sucks

Comment: This is a developer  site, Josh. For us, Firefox doesn't suck or not. It's just what our users use. Most of us code our own browsers every January and use those. I'm personally in version 15. You?

Comment: @Josh : What a wonderful comment ! Firefox just has the right behaviour and does what it is intented to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, this is impossible, except maybe with IE and an ActiveX, but I seriously suggest you not to use it.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll keep hoping. Solution will have to be cross-platform, though, so IE and ActiveX is out.