# PHP force browser downloading image, Facebook like

Tags: php

I am looking for a way to force the browser to download an image instead of just display it.

I already looked a lot (and deeply) and there seems to be **no standard way to do it** properly.

The way Facebook do it, it's with some PHP I guess they put a parameter at the end :
**?dl=1**

So it's certainly a PHP page behind with an url rewritting i guess

```
<a class="itemAnchor" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"  href="http://a5.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/327910_2733459209258_1040639162_2895571_6924037615_o.jpg?dl=1" rel="ignore"><span class="itemLabel fsm">Download</span></a>
```

So if you have any clue how they do it... My clue is that they probably do something in the headers of the PHP page

Comment: You might want to give this article a read: http://www.ryboe.com/tutorials/php-headers-force-download
Seems to be exactly what you're after, as long as you're actually serving the image yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They simply *force downloading* using HTTP headers just like you do with any other file:

```
<?php
    $file = 'C:\\test.jpg';

    header('Cache-Control: public');
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Type: '.mime_content_type($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));

    readfile($file);
?>
```

---

**X-SendFile**

For larger files or busy webservers, I would suggest the use of [X-SendFile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) header instead of using `readfile()` function (note that you need `mod_xsendfile` installed in Apache).

```
    header('X-Sendfile: '.$file);
    //readfile($file);
```

---

**.htccess**

As you noticed, the Facebook URL points at a jpg file, rather than a PHP one.
You will need to have URL rewriting in a `.htaccess` file to do this trick.

Something like the following should work (note you will need to use the real URL, checking the contents of `$_SERVER` to do so).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: what do you put in the headers then?

Comment: i should use this: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-19.5.1 as attachement?

Comment: ahaha you compete to have my "accept answer" you were the fastest i will accept yours i have to wait 5 more min ;)
Your answer is perfect thanks again :)

Comment: Very elaborated/detailed answer. +1

Comment: Practice makes perfect ;). Happy to help!

Comment: yes i was ok with the .htaccess and PHP just the headers parameters that i didn't really know, but your answer will definitely help others as well i think ;)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to define the [`Content-Disposition`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html) variable in your [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

```
<?php
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='downloaded.png'");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by setting the appropriate headers before sending the file. Specifically you can set the `Content-Type` to whatever your content type is and `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=<yourfilename>`.

There are some gotchas with IE; check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943998/how-do-i-force-users-to-download-image-like-downloading-pdf) for more info.

Comment: ok thanks i got it, i really looked at it for a long time so great! ;)