# Force a download link once image is resized

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I am working on a wordpress cms. I have a little no-fancy php script which basically resizes the uploaded image to assigned limits, and outputs the resized image back to the visitor's browser, so he can right-click-download. Given below is a relevant portion of the script, but if need I shall provide complete code.

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($new, null, 100); 
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode(ob_get_clean()) . '">';
echo '<br><br>RIGHT CLICK AND SAVE IMAGE<br><br>';
imagedestroy($new);
```

---

> Bottomline is I would like to force the download link for the resized
>   image, once resize is done.

---

**EFFORTS AND UPDATES:**

`First update`: I am currently going through [this article on forced-download-links](http://www.ryboe.com/tutorials/php-headers-force-download) as suggested on [another relevant thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916599/php-force-browser-downloading-image-facebook-like?lq=1). But I am stcuk when it says - "First things first… we need to define the path to our file in PHP (as a string).". Problem is, since I do not want any image file saved on my server and so the second parameter of the [imagejpeg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) function is set to `NULL`. So I cannot define a path to my file. Or can I ? How do I do this. Hope it was clear and concise. A solution would be great, if not please give me good starting pointers.

`Second update` : According to the suggestion below I have made some progress. As you can see in the code below, I am able to now save the image, but i am still unable to echo out the output image as a download prompt. Please suggest a correction.

```
$filename = uniqid();
$file = 'uploads/'.$filename.'.jpeg';   
$final_image = imagejpeg($new, $file, 100);
$size = filesize($file); 

header("Content-Type: application/force-download; name=\"" . basename($file). "\""); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header("Content-Length: $size"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file) . "\""); 
header("Expires: 0"); 
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
readfile($file); 
unlink($file);
```

`Third Update` : Found out that I can use relative paths so I dont need to load wordpress load.php, changed the code accordingly. Issue still remains.

Fourth Update : Tried this code as suggested in solutions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948178/php-file-force-download?rq=1). Same result, prints out gibberish instead of offering a download link. This is getting frustrating, I must be getting close :).

**Final Update** : There was javascript parsing the output of the script, so I was getting all gibberish. I removed it now everything is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one solution is that you save the image in your server with  imagejpeg() after that force download and delete the file you will have something like this :

```
$img = imagejpeg($resource, $file);
$size = filesize($file); 
header("Content-Type: application/force-download; name=\"" . basename($file). "\""); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header("Content-Length: $size"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file) . "\""); 
header("Expires: 0"); 
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
readfile($file); 
unlink($file); //to delete the file that you generated
```

where $file is the file path the `unlink` function to delete that file.

You can also force download directly like this :

```
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"titleimg\";");
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
```

Regards,

Comment: the second block of code prints out gibberish instead offering a link. Still trying to figure out the first one.

Comment: try to test with is_directory, is your path relative to your script? a hint : use __DIR__ constant to get your current script direction

Comment: path is not an issue anymore, I have solved it. Please check my efforts update in progress, as you can see i have adapted your code from the first block. But it just outputs jibberish and does not prompt a download at all.

Comment: There was javascript parsing the output of the script, so I was getting all gibberish. I removed it now everything is okay. But although you solution ( first code block ) works, the image downloaded does not display on windows photo viewer and shows display error while trying to open in firefox.